# How to update kafka config of already existing topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka

For creation I am using

```
@Bean
public NewTopic userTopic(final KafkaTopicConfiguration userConfig) {
    return TopicBuilder.name(userConfig.getName())
        .partitions(userConfig.getPartitions())
        .replicas(userConfig.getReplicas())
        .configs(userConfig.getConfigs())
        .build();
}
```

Initially, I thought that restarting the app with new config properties will update the topic configuration as it does for partitions, but config nor replicas are not updated.

How to update config specifically during app start? Is there a specific bean that can be defined to do that automatically?

Comment: Are you running multi-node Kafka cluster?

Comment: This is more Apache Kafka question: Spring does nothing in this matter, but just delegates to respective API of Kafka Client.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Im asking about spring integration so it can be a spring related.

Comment: @SounakSaha yes

Comment: Well, technically you need to learn what plain Kafka Client (or even its protocol) can do, then you raise your concern against Spring. The integration definitely cannot do you more than client allows.

Comment: I know that Kafka Client can update configuration, I've just been concerned that NewTopic actually updates partition numbers but not anything else.

Comment: There is an open issue to support changing other properties https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1482 right now, only the partition count can be increased automatically; use an `AdminClient` for other changes.

Comment: Nice, can you post an answer for question so I can close?